# simple NSDate from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

all I want is a date like this: 01/06/1973 as an NSDate.

I assumed this would do the trick:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
            NSDate *myDate =[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01/06/1973" ];
```

but my formatting is not being followed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would need to be slighty modified, like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
            oldestDate =[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01/06/1973" ];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am assuming here that your date 01/06/1973 is the 6th of Jan 1973. Move the month (MM), day (dd) and year (yyyy) around in the dateFormatter if it's not the above

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate =[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01/06/1973" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try @"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" as your formatting string?